# How could I calculate if XY coordinate is within certain area?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

So lets imagine that I have a grid of 10x10 (can be any size, but just for the sake of example say 10), and with that grid there is 3 points marking vertexes of a triangle (again can be any amount of points delimiting any arbitrary shape).

So my question is.. Is there a way given just this information to determine programatically if any given coordinate is within that shape?

Lest say the coordinates are 3,2-7,3-5,5. Can I while iterating over the given grid pick out the cells that fall within these points?

Comment: This may help you in your research: this problem is commonly known as [point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

Comment: Do you want to check whether a couple of points are in a polygon, or do you have a grid and want to determine *all* squares that are part of the polygon? The first is the aforementioned point-in-polygon problem, the latter is rasterization and requires quite different algorithms (if you want it to be efficient).

Comment: For the convex case, it is pretty easy, but you said 'any abitrary shape', so I assume you will have non-convex shapes. Is that correct?

Comment: @delnan, I need to determine all the points that are in the polygon.

Comment: @TobiLehman yes, can be non-convex as well. It is for creating cellular automaton simulations, that are non-rectangular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call P the point that you are checking, and S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,...,S<sub>n</sub> the n vertices of the shape.

Assume that P ≠ S<sub>i</sub> for all i.

1. Is P on the boundary?
2. If 1 is no, then randomly choose a line L that passes through P
3. Pick a point F that you know is outside the polygon
4. Follow the sequence of intersections of L with the shape from F until you hit P (Call the Sequence F, ..., P)
5. Count the sequence F, ..., P, store the value in M
6. If M is even, then P is in the polygon, Otherwise P is not in the polygon

NOTE: By introducing the starting point F, we change the parity mentioned in [the point in polygon algorithm description on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

Comment: Note that OP wants to check this for *all* points. They are effectively rasterizing. Running a point-in-polygon query for so many points is rather less efficient than an algorithm that enumerates all points wholesale.

Comment: That's a good point, although it could be reduced in half by choosing two points P and P', and then applying steps 4-6 on both P and P'.